# PostgreSQL where clause condition check with value that contains single quote

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-constant

Suppose I have an `employees` table in Postgres DB where I have to insert a value for an employee name which is `john's`

Since it's Postgres I will escape the single quote `'` by doubling them up -> `''`

So `john's` will become `john''s`

Now when I select that particular row/instance using **select query** I  have to double the quote again. So to select the value `john''s` I have to write `'john''''s'` and my query becomes -

```
select * from employees where name = 'john''''s'
```

Is this the best approach? or
Is there any alternative to this process of data insertion and selection for these particular type of data (contains quote)? Any suggestion ?

Comment: "*Since it's Postgres I will escape the single quote*" - that has nothing to do with "being Postgres". This is what the SQL standard requires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't have to double the escaped quotes:

```
select * 
from employees 
where name = 'john''s'
```

Comment: Thank you. But It doesn't work on my Database. I have to use the above-mentioned method. I'm using 'PostgreSQL 13.0'.

Comment: @ahmedshahriar: this will most definitely work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=399f7b01d8b5b9fe699f2c25f8956d87 if it doesn't for you, then there is something you are not telling us

Comment: Thnx. You're correct. Actually, I'm using psycopg2 and mogrify function to perform bulk insert from JSON and the column type is "character varying". So my guess is whenever I convert the JSON into bytestring to insert data using mogrify (after adding single escape quote) it again adds an extra quote. That's why I have to use double quotes in my query.